# Associate POD Spec attributes to different Build Settings from their Xcode Configuration (e.g. Release, Debug)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, build-settings

I'm trying to create a POD spec for an existing library project.

In the Xcode project, the build settings define different Preprocessor macros for different Build Configurations (e.g.: "Debug" and "Release")

For example:

For the "Debug" Configuration:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
```

For the "Release" Configuration:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = NDEBUG NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
```

**How do I map these settings to the corresponding POD spec?**

For example:

```
spec.compiler_flags = '-DDEBUG=1'
```

and

```
spec.compiler_flags = '-DNDEBUG -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS'
```

Unfortunately, the official documentation in general is mostly more confusing and unclear, than really helpful:

[Build settings](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#group_build_settings)

> **Build settings**
>
> In this group are listed the attributes related to the configuration of the build environment that should be used to build the library.
>
> If not defined in a subspec the attributes of this group inherit the value of the parent.
>
> Examples:
>
> spec.compiler_flags = '-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0', '-Wno-format'

Intuitively, I would do something like this:

```
configuration :Debug do
    spec.compiler_flags = '-DDEBUG=1'
end

configuration :Release do
    spec.compiler_flags = '-DNDEBUG -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS'
end
```

However, that's guessing.

Comment: I am looking for the answer of this exact question, do you have any update?

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

I was too quick to jump to this solution, and actually, ***this one does not work***.

While [Conditional Variable Assignment](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html#ConditionalVariableAssignment) of xcconfig syntax does set a value conditionally for architecture and platform, it works differently for configuration.
Due to this difference, this solution doesn't get along with CocoaPods' xcconfig inheritance mechanics.

OP of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29241458) apparently, and also I, could not successfuly use Conditional Variable Assignment for configuration in podspec.

---

Using [Conditional Variable Assignment](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html#ConditionalVariableAssignment) of xcconfig syntax, you can achieve it:

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Debug]' => '-DDEBUG=1',
    'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Release]' => '-DNDEBUG -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS'
}
```

Yet, there is a small side effect, as mentioned in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23943601), where resulting build settings will be defined multiple times in Pod.xcconfig somehow.