# Cocoapods specify podspec xcconfig value for Debug only

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I am using cocoapods and want to specify a value in the pod's podspec using the xcconfig parameter that would be specific to Debug mode.

currently, using :

```
s.xcconfig = { "GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" => "MY_DEFINE=1" }
```

will set the value for both Debug and Release modes.  Also tried using :

```
s.xcconfig = { "GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Debug]" => "MY_DEFINE=1" }
```

but, altho this sets it in the pod's preprocessor macros, it doesn't seem to register during execution of the code, unlike when not using the [config=Debug] tag.  Is there a way to limit it to Debug mode only?

Answer (score 5):

You should create two separate podspec's each with different xcconfig and then use configurations to link to each of them:

```
pod 'my-podspec-debug', :configurations => ['Debug']
pod 'my-podspec-release', :configurations => ['Release']
```

See this old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26074997/1509221

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this for a while. Does this mean two separate pods will have to be registered in the spec repo? Or can you have two podspecs within a master spec?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you need by adding this in your podspec file:

```
 s.xcconfig = { "GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" => "$(GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_$(CONFIGURATION))",  
                "GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_Debug" => "MY_DEFINE=1" }
```

You can use Variable Substitution to assign a value to GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS based on an other variable that its name your create based on the on the build configuration name(i.e. GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_$(CONFIGURATION)).

You can read more here https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html#VariableSubstitution